# await an await function

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I am trying to use async/await function but with a different line of execution and I would like to know if something like that is possible.

I have the following code:

```cs
public class Example
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething Start:");
        DoMore();
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething End:");
    }

    public async void DoMore()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoMore Start:");
        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
        Console.WriteLine("DoMore End:");
    }
}
```

When I call `DoSomething` I will get:

```
DoSomething Start:
DoMore Start:
DoSomething End:
DoMore End:
```

I want the thread that executes DoSomething to wait **in a non blocking way** for DoMore to end and then continue execution of DoSomething (something like using await on the DoMore call).
The resulting output should be:

```
DoSomething Start:
DoMore Start:
DoMore End:
DoSomething End:
```

I can use the following code:

```cs
public class Example
{
    public async void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething Start:");
        await Task.Run(() => DoMore());
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething End:");
    }

    public async void DoMore()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoMore Start:");
        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
        Console.WriteLine("DoMore End:");
    }
}
```

but that uses a different thread for DoMore which I don't need.

Comment: Yes, I am getting "cant await void methond" error

Comment: Do you just mean that you want to await DoMore?  Then return a Task instead of void, so you can await it.  This is not only possible, it’s preferred.  Async void only exists for backward compatibility on event handlers, it should never be used outside of that.

Comment: => go async all the way.

Comment: If you make DoSomething async then simply await DoMore. The Task.Run stuff is unnecessary. And the `Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));` hurts my eyes. A simple `Task.Delay` should do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)

Comment: Some further information on why `async void` is discouraged: https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#async-void

Comment: Note that your work-around isn't guaranteed (or even likely) to behave the way you want; it can produce the same output as calling directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling your code from an `async` method gives the compilation error *CS4008: Cannot await 'void'*. The solution is **replacing the two `void` types with `Task`** and calling `DoSomething()` from an async method. The crucial point is that [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and use async all the way down.

This will do the job:

```cs
public class Example
{
    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething Start:");
        await DoMore();
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething End:");
    }

    public async Task DoMore()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoMore Start:");
        await Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(1000));
        Console.WriteLine("DoMore End:");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
DoSomething Start:
DoMore Start:
DoMore End:
DoSomething End:
```

Comment: That is intresting, I have to admit that I am little weak on Task as a return value.
I will read more about Task, but in the meantime, DoSomething can be async void and it will work perfectly, is it advised for DoSomething to be async void or async Task?

Comment: You should always use `async Task` when you do not return a value. The only exception to this is event handler methods, where you don't have a chance to change the `void` return type.

Answer (score -1):

You method should return `Task`, and being async you can either await its execution or let it run in a separate context:

```
public class Example
{
    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething Start:");
        await DoMore(); //awaiting
        vat t = DoMore(); //parallel, but you can't be sure when the execution is over
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething End:");

        await t; //until you await the task obj
    }

    public async Task DoMore()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoMore Start:");
        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
        Console.WriteLine("DoMore End:");
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't even compile. You cannot `await` in a non-`async` method.

Comment: @Fildor you're right I forgot to edit. Thanks!

Comment: Why not `await Task.Delay(1000);`?

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need your method **DoSomething()** to be asynchronous, you simply can add the **Wait()** method to your method flow as follows.
Just remember to add Task as return value in the **DoMore()** method.

```
new Example().DoSomething();
public class Example
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething Start:");
        DoMore().Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething End:");
    }

    private async Task DoMore()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoMore Start:");
        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
        Console.WriteLine("DoMore End:");
    }
}
```

Please read: [C# Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-8.0)

Edit:

If you are looking a non blocking way to run multiple "parallel" tasks, you can use that approach.

```
new Example().DoSomething();
public class Example
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething Start:");
        var t1 = DoMore();
        var t2 = DoMore2();
        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething End:");
    }

    private async Task DoMore()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoMore Start:");
        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
        Console.WriteLine("DoMore End:");
    }

    private async Task DoMore2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoMore2 Start:");
        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
        Console.WriteLine("DoMore2 End:");
    }
}
```

You can't wait to obtain the output:

> DoSomething Start:
> DoMore Start:
> DoMore End:
> DoSomething End:

If you don't use the await/Wait() tools the code at some point.

Comment: This will give the expected output but the OP wants to wait in a *non blocking* way. `Wait()` will block.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the post's author is looking for a non blocking way, with a necessarily blocking code. That is not possible. Adding "**async Task**" keywords to the **DoSomething** method needs a blocking way to obtain the output on the console.